# How to get JWT token information in a Service in asp.net core api?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to access the token informations like claims of stored token in a service. I have tried injecting `AuthorizationHandlerContext` in my service. But the api can't to resolve the `AuthorizationHandlerContext` and throws exception. Is there any other way to access the token information inside a service?

Comment: What's asp.net core version are u on? What's in your Startup class? It would be better if u provided this info. Otherwise, try HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpAuthenticationFeature>() as u'll get a ClaimsPrincipal through this to examine the claims.

Comment: Are you using identity server 4 for token generation..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject `IHttpContextAccessor` to  your service then get all user claims or user information from the **JWT**

Register `IHttpContextAccessor` into **DI**

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

```
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
public YourService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
    _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
}
```

```
var username =_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code on OnAuthorization(IAuthorizationFilter) action:

```
  string email=context.HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "email").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to access the JWT token informations, A more structured approach will be,

> Step 1. Create a Model

```
    public class AuthorizedUser
    {
        public ClaimsPrincipal Claims { get; set; }        
    }
```

> Step 2. Use this model inside your authorized Controller method. like:

```
    [Authorized]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Modify([FromForm] RequestDto dto)
    {
        var user = new AuthorizedUser()
        {
            Claims = User
        };
        return Ok(await _service.MakeChanges(user, dto));
    }
```

> Step 3. Create an extension function for ease of access

```
   public static string GetUserId(this ClaimsPrincipal claims)
   {
        return claims.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "sub")
            .Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();
   }
```

> Step 4. Simply access that users claims and other JWT properties like,

```
    public Task<object> MakeChanges(AuthorizedUser user, RequestDto dto){
          var userId = user.Claims.GetUserId();
    }
```

That's it.